# How to alias all methods from an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, interpreter, interactive

I'm creating a script that's actually an environment for other users to write code on.

I've declared several methods in a class and instantiate an object so users can use those methods as simple interpreter functions, like so:

```
from code import interact

class framework:
    def method1(self, arg1):
    # code for method1
    def method2(self, arg2):
    # code for method2

def main():
    fw = framework()

    # Aliases
    method1 = fw.method1
    method2 = fw.method2

    interact(local=locals())
```

Since I don't want the user to call the methods with `fw.method1(arg)`, I setup aliases. The problem is, since the framework class is under development, I have to keep updating the main script with new aliases for the methods I create.

Is there a simple way of getting rid of the "`fw.`" part on the calls and have all the methods under class framework automatically visible under main?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You control the dictionary passed to `interact`, so put what you want in it without worrying with local variables in `main`:

```
d={}
for n in vars(framework):
  if n.startswith('_'): continue  # probably
  x=getattr(fw,n)
  if callable(x): d[n]=x
interact(local=d)
```

This works for regular, static, and class methods.  It doesn’t see instance attributes (unless they’re shadowing a class attribute) or inherited methods.

The former matters only if the instance stores functions as attributes (in which case you might or might not want them available).  The latter is convenient in that it omits `object`; if there are other base classes, they can easily be included by searching `framework.__mro__` (and still omitting `object`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you plan to do with the functions, but if they are not `static` it will not likely work outside of the class:

```
fs = [func for func in dir(c) if callable(getattr(c, func)) and not func.startswith("__")]
for func in fs:
    globals()[func] = getattr(c, func)
```

This will put all custom functions within the class `c` to global scope.

Comment: whoa!  you can write to globals()?  and, locals()?  i always assumed they were read-only and that you need an explicit namespace to “pin” generated variable names to.

Comment: You can, they're just dictionaries. Changes to dictionaries stay since they're passed by reference.

Comment: nice. btw i think he’s ok wrt to static - **fw** is an instance of **framework**

Comment: @JLPeyret: You’re not [supposed to write to `locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals), though—it’s (sometimes) merely a representation of the actual local variables.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to do two things:

1. get a list of methods of a class instance
2. dynamically add functions to your local scope

The former can be achieved with the `inspect` module from the standard library, the latter by using `vars`.

Try the following:

```
import inspect

from code import interact

class framework:
    def method1(self, arg1):
    # code for method1
    def method2(self, arg2):
    # code for method2

def main():
    fw = framework()

    # get the methods of fw and update vars().
    # getmembers returns a list of two-tuples with (<Name>, <function>)
    methods = inspect.getmembers(fw, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
    vars().update({method[0]: method[1] for method in methods})

    interact(local=locals())
```

Comment: It’s not safe to modify `locals()` (aka `vars()` with no arguments).  Fortunately, there’s no reason to use *that* dictionary.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why it is not safe and what alternative should be used?
I understand that modifying it might shadow functions with the same name. Are the other disadvantages?

Comment: The doc [says not to](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals).  You can use `exec` in some cases to achieve the effect, but it’s certainly not worth that pain here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something similar to @Davis Herring's answer, fleshed-out and repackaged:

```
#from code import interact

def interact(local):
    local['method1'](42)
    local['method2']('foobar')


class Framework:
    def method1(self, arg1):
        print('Framework.method1({!r}) called'.format(arg1))
    def method2(self, arg2):
        print('Framework.method2({!r}) called'.format(arg2))


def get_callables(obj):
    return {name: getattr(obj, name) for name in vars(obj.__class__)
                if callable(getattr(obj, name))}

def main():
    fw = Framework()

#    # Aliases
#    method1 = fw.method1
#    method2 = fw.method2

    interact(local=get_callables(fw))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Framework.method1(42) called
Framework.method2('foobar') called
```

Comment: Minor point: in Python 3, we shouldn’t ever need to use `x.__class__` instead of `type(x)`.